# SQL XML query for name value pair?

Tags: sql-server, xml

First off i'll start by noting that its not my choice to use nvp's within XML and its in the process of being modified. That being said, I have a table that contains an XML column that has the following xml:

```
<root>
  <results>
    <result name='First Result'>
      <property name='Property1' value='Value1' />
      <property name='Property2' value='Value2' />
    </result>
  </results>
</root>
```

I have the following query that gets me the result name:

```
SELECT
  T.N.value('@name', 'nvarchar(256)') AS resultName
FROM
  results CROSS APPLY xmlField.nodes('/root/results/result') AS T(N)
```

But I'm not positive how I could get the property to display. I tried the following:

```
SELECT
  T.N.value('@name', 'nvarchar(256)') AS resultName,
  T.N.value('/property[@name="Property1"]/@value', 'nvarchar(256)') AS Property
FROM
  results CROSS APPLY xmlField.nodes('/root/results/result') AS T(N)
```

But I got the following error:

XQuery [results .xmlField.value()]: 'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *'

I know I'm along the right path, but I'm not quite positive what exactly I should be doing. Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
SELECT 
  T.N.value('../@name','varchar(255)') as resultName,
  T.N.value('@name', 'nvarchar(256)') AS Propertyname ,
  T.N.value('@value', 'nvarchar(256)') as Value      
FROM 
    results
        cross apply
  xmlfield.nodes('/root/results/result/property') AS T(N) 
where
     T.N.value('@name', 'nvarchar(256)') ='property1'
```

OR

```
SELECT 
  T.N.value('@name', 'nvarchar(256)') AS resultName,
  T.N.value('(./property[@name="Property1"]/@value)[1]', 'nvarchar(256)') AS Property 
FROM 
  results CROSS APPLY xmlField.nodes('/root/results/result') AS T(N)
```

Comment: Close, but I would like to have the filtering available in the select fields, as that will allow me to control exactly what properties I am getting back.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'm still not explaining what I'm looking for very well. The where clause limits it to only one entity. I'm specifically trying to do the filtering in the xquery so that I can alias the field with the known property name. I guess its more of an xquery question at this point. Thanks for the help though, your answer is giving me more ideas to think about.

Comment: I think what you might be looking for is the `sql:variable()` syntax?

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Every time I tried I was using `/property` instead of `./property`, but this solved it! Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

Try to lookup for first matching node in your xpath.

```
SELECT   organizationDeviceId,   
         T.N.value('@name', 'nvarchar(256)') AS resultName,   
         T.N.value('(/property[@name="Property1"])[1]/@value', 'nvarchar(256)') AS Property
       FROM results CROSS APPLY xmlField.nodes('/root/results/result') AS T(N)
```

I am not 100% sure about the result but need to use `[1]` to lookup for first result.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the query, but I am getting NULL for the Property field. This gives me some more thoughts on things to try though.